# Is samsung galaxy watch 5 Pro cabable of development and programming apps on it

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-galaxy

I have a Samsung galaxy watch 5 pro running the latest version of WearOS 3
I want to build an app that use the watch sensors and send the reading into android smartphone

there are the WearOS android SKD which is closer to android developer
and there is Samsung Privileged Health SDK
what is the difference between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can obviously develop apps for Wear OS. As for Samsung Privileged SDK: it is compatible both with Wear OS and Galaxy Watch (4 and above according to their website).

The difference is in API itself. While it might be similar in functionality you will see differences. Please, refer to the official documentation as it is too much broad question.

Comment: have you tried working with these APIs, especially the Samsung SDK

Comment: @MohamedShqierat no, unfortunately, I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

You can but require to fill Samsung Privileged Health SDK form. It is ugly step of Samsung, while the SDK must be easy for devs using it, they require fill very long form in order to submit the form, and some devs never able to access to the SDK.